# mxGraph custom user object with xml children element read and write

Tags: jquery, xml, mxgraph

In the mxGraph tutorial page, the custom user object can be parameterized by using graph.insertVertex() method.

[mxCell with custom user object value](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/model/mxCell-js.html)

The custom user object is with xml format defined by the template in the wfeditor-commons.xml contained in the workflow editor examples.

But what's a better way to build the children elements through HTMLCollection? The below xml is my own defined template, I need to maintain Description and ActivityType children element if some value has been changed.

```
<add as="task">
  <Activity label="Task" name="" code="">
    <Description/>
    <ActivityType type="TaskNode"/>
        <mxCell vertex="1"> 
            <mxGeometry as="geometry" width="72" height="32"/>
        </mxCell>
    </Activity>
</add>
```

To access the children xml element Description and ActivityType node by these codes:

```
var model = this.graph.getModel();
var snode = model.getSelectedCell();  //to get current selected cell
var id = snode.id;
var label = $(snode).attr("label");   //get xml node attribute

var descriptionNode = $(snode.value).children("Description");
var descriptionTextContent = $(descriptionNode).text();    //get xml node text
var activityTypeNode = $(snode.value).children("ActivityType");
var activityTypeAttr = $(activityTypeNode).attr("type");   //get xml node attribute
```

I am not sure wether this is an effective method to implement the custom user object read and write through HTMLCollection.

By the way, If the custom user object children elements have been changed, and need to be saved. How to set the node attribute and text content value? After changed these values, it also need to call set value method to refresh the user object. Thanks

```
model.setValue(cell, newValue)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the begining, there is a confuing about jQuery xml selector and the MS XML DOM object method. After some researching work for MS XML DOM knowledge, thers is a nice solution for reading and writing user object.

//read method

```
    var model = kmain.mxGraphEditor.graph.getModel();
    var snode = model.getValue(cell);

    var activity = {};
    activity.id = snode.getAttribute("id");
    activity.name = snode.getAttribute('label');
    activity.code = snode.getAttribute('code');

    var descriptionNode = snode.getElementsByTagName("Description")[0];    //child node
    if (descriptionNode) activity.description = descriptionNode.textContent;

    //activity type
    var activityTypeNode = snode.getElementsByTagName("ActivityType")[0];   //child node
    activity.type = activityTypeNode.getAttribute("type");
```

//write method

```
    var snode =  model.getValue(kmain.mxSelectedDomElement.Cell);

    snode.setAttribute('label', activity.name);   //set attribute value
    snode.setAttribute('code', activity.code);    //set attribute value

    var descriptionNode = snode.getElementsByTagName("Description")[0]; 
    if (!descriptionNode){
        descriptionNode = snode.appendChild(snode.ownerDocument.createElement('Description'));    //add child element
    }
    descriptionNode.textContent = activity.description;         //set element text

    var activityTypeNode = snode.getElementsByTagName("ActivityType")[0];
    activityTypeNode.setAttribute("complexType", activity.complexType);
```

This will make it easy to maintain custom user object for mxGraph users.